# Get the length of a string by its final NUL element

Tags: c, string

I'm programming some functions to treat with strings without using `<string.h>`, and I'm getting the length of a string by doing this:

```
char *str= "Getting the length of this";
int c;
for (c= 0; str[c]!='\0'; c++);
```

Now `c` is the length of my string so it makes work with strings a lot easier, but i wonder if this is correct (it works but maybe is not a proper way to do this).

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Your code is correct

Comment: `str` would be better off being declared `const char *`, since any modification of a string literal (which is what `str` points at [the first character of]) gives undefined behaviour.     Beyond that, your code as it stands is correct, but there is a function in the C standard library which does exactly the same thing as your third line - `strlen()`, which is declared in `<string.h>`.

Comment: `NULL` is the null-pointer literal and different from the character `NUL`  used to terminate a  C-string.

Comment: Your code is correct. But the compiler often knows about `strlen` (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) thru `__builtin_strlen` used in  `<string.h>`) and will compile it more efficiently. In some cases your code might be converted by the optimizing compiler to a call to `strlen` or similar (more efficient) code.

Comment: Your code is not very readable. Any reader would ask himself why is `strlen` not used, and you might add a comment to explain why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...  i wonder if this is correct

Yes, it is correct.

For readability I would prefer:

```
char *str= "Getting the length of this";
int c = 0;
while(str[c]) c++;
```

but that's just a matter of taste.

Be aware that it is unusual to use `int` for string length. The `strlen` function returns `size_t` so to mimic the library function, you should also use `size_t` Like:

```
size_t my_strlen(const char* s)
{
    size_t c = 0;
    while(s[c]) c++;
    return c;
}


char *str= "Getting the length of this";
size_t c = my_strlen(str);
```

Comment: Using `const` would be better

Comment: while(s[c]) c++; what if s is NULL ?

Comment: @potato - By contract you are not allowed to call `strlen` with a NULL pointer. That goes for many of the string functions. And **if** you do, you're in trouble...